# How to add duplicates or merge entries in a complex list?

Tags: c#, excel, list, merge, duplicates

I have a problem that I thought would be easy to solve but after a couple of days of failed attempts I'm asking for help.

I have a table in Excel that looks like this:

| Transaction Date | Bank Account | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44287 | Account 1 | 500 |
| 44287 | Account 1 | -700 |
| 44287 | Account 2 | -200 |
| 44286 | Account 1 | 300 |
| 44286 | Account 3 | -150 |

The table represents multiple bank accounts and I want to obtain the cumulative balance for each date across all accounts. So for example the output I expect is:

| Transaction Date | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 44287 | -900 |
| 44286 | 150 |

If there are multiple transactions from the same account on a given date, for example on "44287" the balance of Account 1 had two values, so I would take the maximum absolute value which is -700 (and ignore 500). I'm using the default date number notation from Excel for simplicity.

I've exhausted all my options in Excel so I created my own simple Console App in C#.

This is what I have so far.

I'm reading the input from Excel into a `var data = new List<List<string>>();`. The first outer list stores the columns and the second inner list stores the rows. So for instance `data[2][3]` would equal `-200`.

```
private static void Calculate(string filePath, string sheetName)
{
    var data = new List<List<string>>();

    using (ExcelReader excel = new ExcelReader(filePath))
    {
        excel.SetWorksheet(sheetName);
        data = excel.ReadUsedRangeToList();
    }

    var date = data[0];
    var account = data[1];
    var balance = data[2];

    // group transactions by date
    var groupedByDate = new List<List<List<string>>>();
    for (int r = 1; r < date.Count - 2; r++)
    {
        var lines = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int ri = r; ri < date.Count; ri++)
        {
            if (date[r] == date[ri])
            {
                var temp = new List<string>();
                temp.Add(date[ri]);
                temp.Add(account[ri]);
                temp.Add(balance[ri]);

                lines.Add(temp);

                // need to set r to the latest ri to finish at the last line
                r = ri;
            }
            else
            {
                r = ri - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        groupedByDate.Add(lines);
    }
}
```

I firstly grouped my original list into a new list which groups the data also by date. This however adds another depth level to the list. Then I tried to group that by bank account but this would add another level to the list and the logic with all these loops is becoming mind blowing.

I am beginning to think I took a wrong approach to solve this problem. I did a lot of googling and it seems like it might be better to go with LINQ instead of using loops? I used LINQ before but only for very trivial things.

If anyone could just even point me in the right direction that would be great. I'm open to all ideas. If someone knows if you can do this easily in Excel which I may have missed let me know too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, you can do this using `Power Query`.

See the comments and explore the Applied Steps window to understand the algorithm, which I think is what you want:

You may need to edit the data types to reflect decimal numbers and dates.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
            {"Transaction Date", Int64.Type}, {"Bank Account", type text}, {"Balance", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by Date and Account
//Extract the amount corresponding to maximimum absolute value for each date/account grouping
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Transaction Date", "Bank Account"}, {
        {"useBal", each List.Accumulate([Balance],0,(current,status)=> if Number.Abs(status) > Number.Abs(current)
                        then status else current)}
        }),
 
 //Then group by date and SUM the balances
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"Transaction Date"}, 
        {{"Balance", each List.Sum([useBal]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows1"
```

[image]

**NOTE**

***M Code modified to use "proper" data types***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
            {"Transaction Date", type date}, {"Bank Account", type text}, {"Balance", Currency.Type}}),

//Group by Date and Account
//Extract the amount corresponding to maximimum absolute value for each date/account grouping
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Transaction Date", "Bank Account"}, {
        {"useBal", each List.Accumulate([Balance],0,(current,status)=> if Number.Abs(status) > Number.Abs(current)
                        then status else current), Currency.Type}
        }),
 
 //Then group by date and SUM the balances
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"Transaction Date"}, 
        {{"Balance", each List.Sum([useBal]),Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea you could do this in Excel. After few more hours of trying I did finally managed to write a solution that works in C#. I guess it did not go in vain as I did learn a few new things - I've attached it for reference in another comment. I will definitely try your approach too as it seems to be a much more efficient method.

Comment: @TheEngineer You're welcome. I edit my answer to show the modification with what I believe would be the desired data types.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have managed to solve my question using LINQ. I did a crash course on YouTube, this is the main [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71medpGp1nc) that helped. I'm posting my solution below for future reference. It might not be optimal but it gets the job done.

```
public class Transaction
{
    public float Date { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}

    private static void Calculate(string filePath, string sheetName)
    {
        // Get raw data from Excel
        var data = new List<List<string>>();
        using (ExcelReader excel = new ExcelReader(filePath))
        {
            excel.SetWorksheet(sheetName);
            data = excel.ReadUsedRangeToList();
        }

        // Organize the data using Transaction class
        var transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        for (int r = 1; r < data[0].Count; r++)
        {
            var transaction = new Transaction();
            transaction.Date = int.Parse(data[0][r]);
            transaction.Account = data[1][r];
            transaction.Value = float.Parse(data[2][r]);

            transactions.Add(transaction);
        }

        // Use LINQ 
        // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71medpGp1nc

        var flattened = new List<Transaction>();
        var groupedByDate = transactions.GroupBy(x => x.Date);
        foreach (var groupDate in groupedByDate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {groupDate.Key} | Count: {groupDate.Count()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {groupDate.Key} | Max: {groupDate.Max(x => x.Value)} | Min: {groupDate.Min(x => x.Value)} | Sum: {groupDate.Sum(x => x.Value)}");

            var groupedByAccount = groupDate.GroupBy(x => x.Account);
            foreach (var groupAccount in groupedByAccount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {groupAccount.Key} | Count: {groupAccount.Count()}");

                var max = groupAccount.Max(x => x.Value);
                var min = groupAccount.Min(x => x.Value);

                float extreme;
                if (Math.Abs(max) > Math.Abs(min))
                {
                    extreme = max;
                }
                else
                {
                    extreme = min;
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {groupAccount.Key} | Max: {groupAccount.Max(x => x.Value)} | Min: {groupAccount.Min(x => x.Value)}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {groupAccount.Key} | Extreme: {extreme}");

                var temp = new Transaction();
                temp.Date = groupDate.ToList()[0].Date;
                temp.Value = extreme;
                flattened.Add(temp);
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("----------");
        }

        // sum the value of all transactions with the same date
        var output = new List<Transaction>();
        var flattenedGroupedByDate = flattened.GroupBy(x => x.Date);

        foreach (var date in flattenedGroupedByDate)
        {
            var temp = new Transaction();
            temp.Value = date.Sum(x => x.Value);
            temp.Date = date.ToList()[0].Date;

            output.Add(temp);
        }
    }
```